# Failing to create a Plone theme templated from Sunburst theme

Tags: plone

I have had problems getting a paster generated theme product to work in my production Plone 4.0 server, so I thought I would try again now that 4.1 is out. I'm now having a different problem: the theme just doesn't show up in the Add-ons list. Here's what I did:

- Installed Plone 4.1 for Windows from Enfold
- Downloaded ez_setup.py, and ran it with Plone's embedded python
- Ran the installed easy_install to get the latest ZopeSkel installed into the embedded Python.
- mkdir src ; cd src ; ..\python\Scripts\paster create -t plone3_theme plonetheme.lt

  Answered the questions so that I'd get a theme based on the plone4 Sunburst theme

  Otherwise I don't touch anything in that generated code.
- cd plonetheme.lt ; ....\python\python.exe setup.py develop  [not sure if I need to do this]
- Edit the buildout.cfg to add plonetheme.lt to the eggs list, and added:
    develop = src/plonetheme.lt
- Run buildout. It mentions that it can find the plonetheme.lt package.
- Start Zeo and Plone servers
- The plonetheme.lt does not appear in the list of Add-ons

What can I have missed? I've poured over the bits of documentation on plone.org and I have Martin Aspeli's books. Many thanks. I've also tried adding the packaging to the zcml slugs, to no avail.

Luke

Comment: """.\python\python.exe setup.py develop [not sure if I need to do this]""" no, you don't need this.

did you add plonetheme.it in the buildout's ZCML section? It is possibile it is not auto-included and zope needs to know where is its configure.zcml.

Comment: Yes, I tried adding it to the slugs section of the buildout. Hopefully it's not that fact that I ran setup.py that's broken it.

Comment: no that's pretty harmless for plone, this is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"cd plonetheme.lt ; ....\python\python.exe setup.py develop [not sure if I need to do this]"*

no this is useless

*"Edit the buildout.cfg to add plonetheme.lt to the eggs list, and added: develop = src/plonetheme.lt"*

you need to add it to the zcml list too.

More info:

Take a look at the step 2 of this guide:
http://plone.org/documentation/kb/add-ons/installing

Comment: Thanks, Giacomo. That was the guide I had been following. Yep, I tried adding it to the zcml list as well, re-buildout, and restart. Still no luck.

Comment: i see. During the paster wizard there was a question saying "Register Profile (Should this package register a GS Profile"? If your said False,then your product will not appear in the control panel...the easier way for you is to re-run the wizard and be sure to respond True to this question.

Comment: Aha - that seemed to do the trick. It is now visible! Many thanks, Giacomo.

Comment: very good, plese mark the question as answered ticking the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the another solution using [buildout.eggtractor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/buildout.eggtractor/)

Or better if you paste your buildout somewhere...

Comment: I hadn't heard of eggtractor - I'll give that a whirl. Thanks.